# extra space with h1 tag

Tags: html, css, alignment

There is unknown space when I add the `h1` tag above the `p` tag.

Here is the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CKRNs/2/)**

What I need is here in the below image

[image]

---

After considering `float:left`, I tried it in my real page but it still gives problem

Here is the new code with `float:left`

**[Fiddle with float](http://jsfiddle.net/CKRNs/19/)**

Comment: That's not how the fiddle aligns for me: http://uploader.pieterhordijk.com/download/39, http://uploader.pieterhordijk.com/download/40

Comment: Are you talking about the gap that the thumb is making? Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/CKRNs/3/) more like it? Otherwise I don't really understand..

Comment: @PeeHaa Fiddle has the problem statement. I need the output like how I have shown in the image.

Comment: HI @Sowmya used to float http://jsfiddle.net/CKRNs/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used to **float** and remove `display inline-block;`

```
   p {
        width: 80%;
        vertical-align: top; margin:0 
    }
    h1{
        font-size:14px; 
        margin:0; 
        vertical-align:top;

    }
    .thumb{
    float:left;
        height:100px    
    }
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CKRNs/5/)**

Comment: Pls look @ the edited question. I added float:left but still it is problem http://jsfiddle.net/CKRNs/19/

Comment: But what did u change in this? removed float from h1??

Answer (score 1):

That's because you have given your `thumb` class (which is your image) a height of 100px. Simply removing that height will fix it, see Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CKRNs/4/

**EDIT**: As you've also said you want the `p` tag next to the image, add `float: left` to both the `p` tag and the `thumb` class, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/CKRNs/6/

Comment: I need p tag to start right below the h1 tag, how it is shown in the attached image

Comment: But in my ral page it is not working.. :( will post the entire code in 2 min. pls have a look

Comment: @Sowmya Okay will do, let me know when you post it.

Comment: @Sowmya See this http://jsfiddle.net/CKRNs/17/ you had missed the `class="thumb"` from the image tag. If you want the image smaller, take the height of the `thumb` class :)

Comment: But still p tag text is not exactly below the h1 text right :( Check here http://jsfiddle.net/CKRNs/19/

Comment: @Sowmya Check this http://jsfiddle.net/CKRNs/20/ I added `margin: 0px` to the `p` tag.

Comment: Hey thanks for your time and answer. Here is the perfect one http://jsfiddle.net/CKRNs/22/

Comment: @Sowmya No problems :) glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

**The problem**: Incorrect use of `display:inline-block;`

**Solution**: Remove all `display:inline-block;` and `vertical-align:top;` occurences and give `.thumb` `float:left;` (the correct way of aligning block elements next to eachother).

**Example**: http://jsfiddle.net/CKRNs/9/

Comment: You also might want to remove the height from the thumb to make the text flow against the image.

Comment: @WouterJ i need the pa tag text to start right below the h1 text. In your fiddle it is displaying next to h1 tag

Comment: @Sowmya what do you mean? The fiddle is exactly what your image is looking like, isn't it?

Comment: @WouterJ you can extend the result part to see the difference in your fiddle. Here is the exact demo http://jsfiddle.net/CKRNs/22/. Anyways thanks for your effort and answer. :)

Comment: @Sowmya oh, I see now. You haven't understand my answer. I said you only need to add `float:left;` to the `.thumb` selector, not to `h1` and `p`.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `float:left;` to the `p`, `h1` and `.thumb` definitions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your image `float:left`. See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CKRNs/14/

Answer (score 0):

```
.thumb{
    display:inline-block;
    height:100px;
        float:left; 
}
```

This means the image will float left and allow the text to wrap

Answer (score 0):

I would use position absolute for the thumb. and put margin-left to the h1 and p tag. http://jsfiddle.net/CKRNs/13/

```
h1, p{
margin: 0 0 0 60px; 
}

.thumb{
  position:absolute;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}
```